# jqgrid call a custom function when clicked on save button in place of edit url

Tags: jqgrid

Below is my code

```
     onSelectRow : function(id) {
        $("#order_list").setGridParam({
            'editurl' : 'clientArray'
            });
           }
        });
jQuery("#order_list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pjmap",{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search: false, refresh:false,cloneToTop:true});
jQuery("#order_list").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#order_list_toppager',{add:false,del:false,edit:true,search: false, refresh:false,cloneToTop:true, viewtext:"View", edittext:"Edit", savetext:"Save", canceltext:"Cancel"});
```

Comment: Your code snipped is incomlete. I tried to fix the code formatting, but my editor blows up. Please post all relevant parts of your code snipped and try to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hei

You can create your own functions for saving by adding a function in parameters for aftersavefunc. My code is like this:

```
 $('#jqGridOutput').navGrid("#jqGridPagerOutput", { edit: false, add: false, del: true, refresh: false, view: false }, {}, {}, delSettings);
    $('#jqGridOutput').inlineNav('#jqGridPagerOutput',
        {
            edit: true,

            del: true,
            add: true,
            cancel: false,
            editParams: {
                aftersavefunc: function (id) { //what should happen on save edit row },
                keys: true,
            },
            addParams: {
                keys: true,
                position: "last",
                aftersavefunc: function (id) { //what should happen on save new row }
            },
        });
```

I think, this is what you are looking for if i understand you correctly?